# how to join two query into one column

Tags: sql-server

```
select  
    Name,
    convert(varchar, Connect, 103) Connect,
    convert(varchar, Connect, 108) Connect,
    Job
from 
    TableWork
where 
    Account ='Account1'
```

Result :

```
Mary | 23/01/2022 | 18:39:00 | Manager
```

I need to join the two columns of times so they look like this:

```
Mary | 23/01/2022 18:39:00 | Manager
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Why are you converting it to a `varchar` in 2 separate columns? It's clearly a date and time data type to start with... Just return the value without converting it.

Comment: it's because I'm converting this "time" :
2022-01-23 18:39:00 ,
to the format like this: 23-01-2022 18:39:00 ,
I didn't even find a conversion code that does this and I tested them all, so I'm trying to join two result

Comment: Formatting is a task for your presentation layer, *not* the SQL layer.

Comment: Is it not possible to join these two results in one column only?

Comment: Or you can use the `FORMAT` function `SELECT FORMAT(Connect, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')` see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6708362e0b770f573570f584c7599b3. Side point: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: You can, @larissabr , but you shouldn't. Do it in the presentation layer and pass your application layer a strongly typed date and time value.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT
  Name,
  convert(varchar, Connect, 103) Connect || ' ' || convert(varchar, Connect, 108) Connect AS Date,
  Job
FROM
  TableWork
Account ='Account1'
```

The || is an operator for string concatenation and whatever you put inside the quotation marks will be concatenated, in this case a white space.

The AS is to indicate a temporal name for the new column, the one formed with the concatenated strings, in this case "Date".

Comment: thank you so much !, that was really what I needed.

Comment: `||` does not work on SQL Server, you need `+`